# More than one keystore or truststore in a machine

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

the Java JVM keystore can be set using system property

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  <...> )
```

I just want to understand , if I want to use another keystore at another path, is it simply just to setproperty again , or does I need to restart the JVM in order for the new path to take effect?

If not, then is there another convenient way to set trustore path , something like a "refresh SSL" so that changes can take effect dynamically?

thanks

Comment: If you want to use another keystore at another path you can use a new variable to store it. if not it will overwrite the existing path and you can use it without restarting jvm.

Comment: hi, i don't understand what you mean. So I just need to do another  `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  new_variable)` ?